# Wakanda server on El Capitan - SMTP send fails

Tags: wakanda

Wakanda Server 10.0 (build 10.181645)running on mac El Capitan.
SMTP send email request fails with this message:
"failed to close SSL socket"

This is after upgrading to El Capitan. Was fine on previous OSX version.

Is there a known issue with El Capitan and Wakanda's SMTP service and/or is a fix available for the service?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried v11 on El Capitan (don't think v10 supports El Capitan) and it works great. Here is my code sample :

```
//creating the email
var mail= require("waf-mail/mail");
var message = new mail.Mail();
message.subject = "Test";
message.from = "support@myWakandaApp.com";
message.to = "YOUR_EMAIL";
message.setBody("This is a test message");

//sending the email
var smtp = require("waf-mail/SMTP");
smtp.send({
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    isSSL: true,
    username: "YOUR_USERNAME",
    password: "YOUR_PASSWORD",
    domain: "myWakandaApp.com"
}, message);
```

Hope it helps,

Yann

Comment: I also have this issue. I also use 4D, so I pass the email info via a text file and send it with 4D.